# Monday as first day of week for WeekArchiveView

Tags: python, django, django-1.3, django-class-based-views, weekday

How do I convince [`WeekArchiveView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.dates.WeekArchiveView) that Monday is the first day of week?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Juding by [this diff](https://mirrors.kilnhg.com/Repo/Mirrors/From-SVN/Django/History/ef8474027dfd), it is achieved by adding `week_format` parameter to `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^items/(?P<year>\d{4})/week/(?P<week>\d{1,2})/$', ItemArchiveView.as_view(
    week_format='%W'
)),
```

Comment: are you answering your own question :?

Comment: @pyInTheSky [I am](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519)